# Qt: Add Widget to Menu

Tags: c++, qt

I created a menu in my `QMainWindow` derived class, and added a `QWidget` to it via `QWidgetAction`. Now my app does not close and stays in infinite loop when I try to close it. Any hints on why this happens?

Here's the code:

```
MainWindow* parent = ...;
auto menu   = parent->menuBar()->addMenu("Menu");
auto action = new QWidgetAction(menu);
auto widget = new QLabel("Lol");
action->setDefaultWidget(widget);
menu->addAction(action);
```

This happens under OSX Sierra, Qt 5.7

Comment: What's `MainWindow::addMenu`?

Comment: @jpo38 sorry, corrected it

Comment: This works perfectly under Windows. There must be a MacOS specific bug here.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#quitOnLastWindowClosed-prop

Comment: Btw, try to `new QWidgetAction(parent);`, not `menu`

Comment: @DmitrySazonov thank you, but already tried it and does not work

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: @DmitrySazonov I simply implemented that code on a QtCreator QMainWindow app and ran it. Does not show anything under Linux and creates an infinite loop on OSX when i close the app

Comment: @manatttta it doesn't matter, where and how you write your code. I'm asking about http://sscce.org/